# Is there a way to force CentOS to do a legacy-style boot install in the UEFI-style installer?

Tags: centos, software-installation, grub2, uefi

I've got a strange situation at work, and I have about 700 systems that all are booting to EFI by default.

I have a PXE menu set up, and I can install CentOS - but the units need to swap to Legacy booting mode to continue in our process.

This presents a problem; once CentOS 7.4 is laid down in UEFI installer mode, it will not boot when the BIOS is swapped to Legacy mode.

How can I force CentOS 7.4, in an automated way, to do a Legacy-style bootloader install while running in UEFI mode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. You can set the platform using `--target` option with `grub2-install` as follows

```
grub2-install --target=i386-pc /dev/sdX
```

`i386-pc` option creates a legacy grub installation even in a `UFI` booted platform.

**NOTE** You must have a small 1Mb unformatted partition with `bios-boot` flag while installing legacy style grub with `gpt` partition table.

You must also have grub create a config file, and then because the installer is in EFI mode, you must replace instances of EFI keywords with Legacy ones.  Here is an example using awk:

```
#EXAMPLE: Normal grub make config command
#grub2-mkconfig > /boot/grub2/grub.cfg

#With awk statement to replace EFI keywords with legacy ones:
grub2-mkconfig |awk '{gsub("linuxefi /", "linux /");gsub("initrdefi /", "initrd /");print $0}' > /boot/grub2/grub.cfg
```

Comment: +1 without the `bios-boot` partition the grub installation will fail.

Comment: I'm having a hell of a time getting this to work. The system reboots to a grub rescue prompt - grub2-install --target=i386-pc /dev/sda also doesn't place a grub.cfg.  When I make it manually, it makes it with EFI linux references.

Comment: @Locane Use `grub2-mkconfig` and redirect the output into `grub.cfg`. It'll auto detect all installed OSs (including Windows, if any) and will generate `grub.cfg` for you.. `grub2-install` is not supposed to generate the configuration.

Comment: Thanks @AbhikBose - I actually got that far (in my comment it says "when I make it manually") - it auto-detects EFI style installation, so the terms "linuxefi" and "initrdefi" replace "linux" and "initrd" respectively.  I was able to get it to work by awking the output and just gusb()ing the terms; so linuxefi->linux and initrdefi->initrd.

Comment: Can you edit your answer to include those two steps? "grub2-mkconfig > /boot/grub2/grub.cfg" and replace all instances of "linuxefi" with "linux" and "initrdefi" with "initrd"?

Comment: @Locane I also though to update it. Busy schedule going on. I'll update it in few days and then delete this comment. Meantime you may also update the answer.